# Angular compile xml like it would be html

Tags: angular, angular-compiler

I would like to create a dynamic xml datasource that can have templates.
Because I already use Angular and have a lot of custom pipes, I would like to work with the Angular syntax and let Angular do the converting and formating for me. 
So basic example:

```
<root>
    <Value>{{Model.MyText}}</Value>
    <Value>{{Model.MyText1 | translate}}</Value>
    <Value>{{Model.ToPay | myNumberPipe: 'curreny'}}</Value>
</root>
```

The result would be:

```
<root>
    <Value>Text</Value>
    <Value>Translated text</Value>
    <Value>1.50€</Value>
</root>
```

So I could prepare an XML with 'raw' data and let Angular do the mapping, translation and the formating.

Is this anyhow possible?

Comment: Did you tried something ??

Comment: Just html did not work, I mean dynamic html string.

Comment: So what you need is, call an api -> the response is something in xml format -> render the response to dom -> tada...  you will get like something shown in example

Comment: ;-D yeah exactly.. the tada is missing..